# XSLT 1.0 Index of node or sibling no

Tags: xslt, count, position

Maybe a noob question, but here goes...

I need to extract the index number of a node that is deep within an xml.

Let's say I'd like to find the index (wich of the int-nodes) that has the value 3 in the following XML:

```
<Result>
 <races>
  <int>2</int>
  <int>3</int>
  <int>4</int>
  <int>5</int>
  <int>6</int>
 </races>
</Result>
```

Anyone got a simple solution for this?

Best regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. From the context of the `/` root node:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(Result/races/int[.='3']/preceding-sibling::int)" />
```

will return the 0-based index number of the specified `int` node (1 in the given example).